# Can't get POST data in API endpoint callback

Tags: api, endpoints

I have this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route('my-project/v1/form', '/post', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'post_form'
  ) );
});
```

I called it with this and the call gets done and serializedForm  is not empty:

```
$(".my-project-submit").click(function(){
   var serializedForm = $('#my-project-form').serialize();
    $.post("/wp-json/my-project/v1/form/post/", serializedForm, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

I tried these:

```
function post_form($data) {
```

$data is null/empty.

```
function post_form($data) {
   $data = $request->get_params();
```

I don't know it $data is null, I just do not receive response ( `alert(data)` never reached).

```
    function post_form($data) {
       $data = $request->get_body();
```

I don't know it $data is null, I just do not receive response ( `alert(data)` never reached).

All test methods end with

```
    $response = new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
    $response->set_headers([ 'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private' ]);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: `$request` is undefined in your examples so it will never work, the parameter passed to the callback is the request object, but you've named yours `$data` for some reason, not `$request`

Comment: Indeed, you should write as answer ;-)

Comment: Additionally, jQuery `serialize` generates a URL encoded string, it's not standard JS practice when using `POST`, and would require additional steps on the PHP end to deserialize

Comment: I would if i knew a full answer at hand, I know it's a part of the issue, but I don't know how to handle the usage of `serialize` in jQuery here. For reference, PHP should be giving you warning and notice messages in your error log for that code due to the use of an undefined variable, so check you've got your debugging setup right and PHP error logs are working

Comment: How should I do it instead of serialize?

(I haven't setup debugging PHP debugging. Long story short, I come from C# where debugging mostly comes in 1 click. Deciding of environment/IDE for PHP developement has been a long headache-process which I'm not sure is becoming stable yet.)

Comment: Well I have now configured xdebug but it's not reaching any php breakpoint anywhere. From Visual Studio point of view, I would say debugged should be "attached to some process" somewhere ... but is still unclear for me in current IDE ( currently using Apache NetBeans )

Comment: You can use PHP error logs without xdebug, and there's a lot of more primitive ways of doing it too, e.g. `WP_DEBUG`. You don't need a full debugger to be able to see warnings/notices/error messages

Comment: Well I realised xdebug is actually working, I just hit the "RUN (F6)" buttons not knowing there was a "Debug (CTRL+F5) button.

But what is still very confusing is that it stop on an unexisting breakpoint in WP's main index.php . Line "define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);" ... so I always have to check if it's not stuck there.

Comment: Found the latter problem was an options to untick. called "Stop at first line".

Comment: Regarding the deserialisation on php side, I just do $data = $request->get_params(); the for exemple $f = $data['first_name']; (first_name being on of the forms fields, and $f contains the right thing.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett you shouldn't use those 3 in a REST endpoint, that's what the request parameter is for, you'd be losing all the validation and sanitising callbacks, as well as any regex parameters. Additionally you should start moving to `filter_input` and more modern methods of getting that data now that cores PHP requirement is being raised

Answer (score 4):

Update your function `post_form` as

```
function post_form(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->get_params();
    print_r($data);
}
```